# Is there anyway to change Wikipedia links to wiki-zero automatically in Google Chrome?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, http, browser

I am trying to figure out a way to forward my Google Search results of Wikipedia pages to be edited as Wiki Zero pages when I click on the link automatically.

For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla

becomes:

https://en.0wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla

Which is:

https://www.wikizeroo.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvTmlrb2xhX1Rlc2xh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by myself for Google Chrome with this extension tool:

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/venividiwiki/hamponpdlhceghibcaciddeoiidpmbaj/related)